# RequireJS async plugin returning error while reading "normalize" property

Tags: javascript, requirejs, require

After adding the [async plugin](https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins) to my RequireJS path to load Google Maps API, I'm getting the error `Cannot read property 'normalize' of undefined`, that is triggered in the line 967 of require.js file (version 2.2.0). The code of my module to load Google Maps API is:

```
define( [ 'async!https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3' ], function() {
    console.log( 'MapsApi!' ); // despite the error, this is executed
} );
```

Executing `require(['async'], function( async ) { console.log(async) } )` on the console returns a valid Object.

I'm not sure about what's happening with the plugin. How can I fix this error?

Comment: I'm getting this weird error, too. In requirejs `plugin` variable is undefined for some reason and `googlemaps!' dependency can't be normilized with this undefined variable.